# How to compare Date in criteriaBuilder.greaterThan()?

Tags: jpa, query-builder, criteria-api

I'm fixing a bug in JAVA/Angular Project, I'm getting a Date in Millisecodes from the front End, then I change the date from Millisecondes to  "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss" format using SimpleDateFormat class in JAVA.
**I want to compare the date that I'm getting from the front end with a field in a Table in my DataBase using criteriaBuilder.greaterThan().**

**The type of the field is bigInit(20).**

I proposed as a solution to compare the dates using TimesTamp type, but the request from the client is a comparaison using Date in JAVA

```
public Specification<T> greater(Object value, String field, String type) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Path tuple = getPath(root, field);
            System.out.println("type" + tuple.getJavaType());
            if (tuple.getJavaType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)) {
                return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(tuple, convertFilterDateToDate(value.toString()));
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(getPath(root,field),Double.valueOf(value.toString()));
        };

}
```

**This method takes 3 parametrs :**

**Object value :** its type is Long in my case, it is the value of the date taken from the front End, I wrote a method to convert the value from Long to Date using SimpleDateFormat.

**String field:** its the field in my table, it contains dates with type Long.

**String Type:** it contains the value 'endDate' in my case.

Below, the definition of getPath Method :

```
public Path getPath(Root<T> root, String field){
        String fiedls[] = field.split("\\.");
        if(!field.contains(".")){
            System.out.print(root.get(field));
            return root.get(field);
        }
        else if (fiedls.length==2){
            Join<Operation,Object> join = root.join(fiedls[0]);
            return join.get(fiedls[1]);
        }
        else if(fiedls.length==3){
            Join<Operation,Object> join = root.join(fiedls[0]);
            Join<Object,Object> join1 = join.join(fiedls[1]);
            return join1.get(fiedls[2]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**The request is to compare date using Date type in java and criteriaBuilder.greaterThan()** , any Idea ?

Comment: you have to put both dates in same format before any comparison can be made.

Comment: @muasif80 yes, I want to compare them using Date format, until now the comparaison is done with Long format

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: @muasif80, its MySQL. I have to compare two dates, I recovre the first date from the frontEnd, its type is Long, and I recovre the second from the database, its type is Long. for the comaraison I'm using criteriaBuilder.greatherThan(). this method takes two parametrs, the first is a Path for the column in the database and the second is the value that I recovered from the fromEnd. the request is to compare them as a Date type  not Long type